# Notification in Statusbar at every day until a certain day is reached

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, alarm

I want to make a Notification that repeats every day at the same time, which is choosen by the user. The user has got also the possibility to decide wheater he will be nofified or not.

Is that possible with the Alarm Manager? Can I stop it or change the repetition with my settings? How can i make it possible that it stops automatically at a certain day?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could you use a Timer with schedule:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Something like

```
this.timer=new Timer();
this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate{
new TimerTask(){
     public void run()
      {
    send_notification();
         }
    },
    0,
    864000000   // Every 86.400 seconds, aka 1 day
);
```

You'll have to experiment, but this should be a good start

Comment: Mmh okay but doesn't this has got a bad performance and costs a lot of battery?

Comment: Mmmh I haven't thought about the battery. It would be a matter of empirical experimentation. However, if you do want to use an Alarm Manager (Which is a good idea!), this example could help you:
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

Comment: Okay and if I want to change the time, I must restart the alarm? If I want to cancel it at a certain day, then I have to cancel it by the Service itself isn't it?

Comment: I think you don't have to restart the alarm, just use the Set() method to change the time. The reference on Android Developers tells us: "(...) If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled (with the equality of two intents being defined by filterEquals(Intent)), then it will be removed and replaced by this one. (...)"
If you want to cancel it at a certain day, you can cancel the Service, or you can Cancel only the Alarm by using the method cancel(). I suggest you this reading:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html